# Querying on a country list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Debugging issue in JavaScript

I need to convert a country name into the respective two digit ISO country code. For the matter, I have created the following object with the initial country variable as a name.

```
var country = 'Andorra' // the input country (I had to throw in the apostrophes because of country names such as "Congo Republic of" that would recognise of as a keyword if not kept in apostrophes.)
var country_code = countrylist[country]
var countrylist = {
'Andorra': 'AD',
'United Arab Emirates': 'AE',
'Afghanistan': 'AF',
'Antigua and Barbuda': 'AG',
'Anguilla': 'AI',
'Albania': 'AL',
'Armenia': 'AM',
'Angola': 'AO',
'Antarctica': 'AQ',
'Argentina': 'AR',
'American Samoa': 'AS',
'Austria': 'AT',
[...]
};
```

country_code should receive 'AD'.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Put the declaration of `countrylist` **before** the point at which you try to use it.

Answer (score 3):

the problem might be that you're defining the countylist object after you try to get information from it.  you need to define countrylist first and then you can retreive information from it.

```
var country = 'Andorra' 

var countrylist = {
'Andorra': 'AD',
'United Arab Emirates': 'AE',
'Afghanistan': 'AF',
'Antigua and Barbuda': 'AG',
'Anguilla': 'AI',
'Albania': 'AL',
'Armenia': 'AM',
'Angola': 'AO',
'Antarctica': 'AQ',
'Argentina': 'AR',
'American Samoa': 'AS',
'Austria': 'AT',
[...]
};

var country_code = countrylist[country] //put this line of code last
```

Comment: _"the problem might be"_ ? You are not sure about it ?

Comment: @Rayon one can never be fully certain of anything can they

Answer (score 2):

You have used variable before it's being declared

You didn't get an error because without **strict mode** javascript does something what is called as **variable hoisting**. [[For more follow this link ]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

For example:

```
bla = 2
var bla;
// ...

// is implicitly understood as:

var bla;
bla = 2;
```

and solution to your problem is to use variable after it's declare and initialised

Example

```
var country = 'Andorra' // the input country (I had to throw in the 

apostrophes because of country names such as "Congo Republic of" that would recognise of as a keyword if not kept in apostrophes.)
var countrylist = {
'Andorra': 'AD',
'United Arab Emirates': 'AE',
'Afghanistan': 'AF',
'Antigua and Barbuda': 'AG',
'Anguilla': 'AI',
'Albania': 'AL',
'Armenia': 'AM',
'Angola': 'AO',
'Antarctica': 'AQ',
'Argentina': 'AR',
'American Samoa': 'AS',
'Austria': 'AT',
[...]
};
var country_code = countrylist[country]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used your countrylist variable before declaring it. You need to move your declaration of country_code to sit below your countrylist varible. Like this:

```
var countrylist = {
'Andorra': 'AD',
'United Arab Emirates': 'AE',
'Afghanistan': 'AF',
'Antigua and Barbuda': 'AG',
'Anguilla': 'AI',
'Albania': 'AL',
'Armenia': 'AM',
'Angola': 'AO',
'Antarctica': 'AQ',
'Argentina': 'AR',
'American Samoa': 'AS',
'Austria': 'AT',
[...]
};
var country_code = countrylist[country]
```